# Can I change the pimary key for feature class comparisons with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, esri-geodatabase, feature-class, comparison, data-management

I'm using ArcPy to compare two feature classes from Esri file geodatabases using the [Feature Compare (Data Management) tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000004000000).
The script itself works very well. However it always uses the OBJECTID to perform the comparison.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1

```
import arcpy

try:
    # Set local variables
    test_features = r'myTestFeatureClass'
    base_features = r'myBaseFeatureClass'

    sort_field = "MyCustomID"
    compare_type = "ALL"
    ignore_option = "IGNORE_M;IGNORE_Z"
    xy_tolerance = "0.001 METERS"
    m_tolerance = 0
    z_tolerance = 0
    attribute_tolerance = "Shape_Length 0.001"
    omit_field = "#"
    continue_compare = "CONTINUE_COMPARE"
    compare_file = r'C:\data\comparefile.txt'


    # Process: FeatureCompare
    compare_result = arcpy.FeatureCompare_management(base_features, test_features, sort_field, compare_type, ignore_option, xy_tolerance, m_tolerance, z_tolerance, attribute_tolerance, omit_field, continue_compare, compare_file)
    print compare_result
    print arcpy.GetMessages()

except:
    # Print error message if an error occurs
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to use a custom ID field for the comparison?
In my script I am using "MyCustomID" as a sort parameter. But the result still lists comparisons based on the OBJECTID.

Comment: Please specify which version of ArcGIS you are using.  You should also edit the question to include the script you're currently using, since it seems that the sort order has a significant impact on how the tool operates.

Comment: You appear to be using more than one user account.  Please use the [instructions for merging accounts](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to do so ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the sort_field(s) to your feature classes then populate the rows with the values of your "MyCustomID" using an update cursor.

Answer (score 0):

The software behaviour that you are observing seems to match the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-compare.htm) where it says:

> The Output Compare File will contain all similarities and differences
>   between the Input Base Features and the Input Test Features. This file
>   is a comma-delimited text file which can be viewed and used as a table
>   in ArcGIS. For example, this table can be queried to obtain all the
>   ObjectID values for all the rows that are different. The "has_error"
>   field indicates that the record contains an error. True indicates
>   there is a difference.

If you know the ObjectID and you know the feature class then it is an easy lookup to find the value(s) for any other field(s) that you are interested in.